# Why can I index into a 3-D array with numbers out of the range and still access the last number in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I am making a program that allows me to play tick-tac-toe with the computer. I created an array of 3 arrays of 3 chars to create the grid.

```
char grid[3][3] = { {' ',' ',' '},
                    {' ',' ',' '},
                    {' ',' ',' '}};
```

I take in input using this format:

```
cout << "\n";
cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
cout << "                                7  |  8  |  9   \n";
cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
cout << "                                4  |  5  |  6   \n";
cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
cout << "                                1  |  2  |  3   \n";
cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
cout << "\n";
```

When the user enters 9, I index into grid[3][-1] using this (input is 9 in this case):

```
grid[input/3][input%3-1] = userMark;
```

and put the user's mark there, but that space is grid[2][2], not grid[3][-1].Can someone explain why I am able to not turn up any errors ans even still play the game after doing this. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is my whole program:

```
#include <iostream.h.>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

char grid[3][3] = { {' ',' ',' '},
                    {' ',' ',' '},
                    {' ',' ',' '}};
char userMark = ' ';
char comMark = ' ';
int difficulty = 0;

showExample();
showGrid();
userMove();
comMove();
reset();
check();

main()
{
    //Asking if the user wants to be Xs or Os
    while(userMark != 'X' && userMark != 'O')
    {
        cout << "\n              Would you like to be Xs or Os? (enter \'X\' or \'O\')\n\n";
        cout << "                                 Mark: ";
        cin >> userMark;
    } 
    if(userMark == 'X')
    {
        comMark = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        comMark = 'X';
    }
    system( "cls");

//Asking the uswer for the difficulty
while(difficulty <1 || difficulty > 3)
{
    cout << "                       Choose the difficulty level!\n\n";
    cout << "                         1) The computer is dumb\n";
    cout << "                         2) You may win\n";
    cout << "                         3) You will never win\n\n";
    cout << "                                level: ";
    cin >> difficulty;
}

//Looping through the game until the use wins or loses
while (check() == 0)
{
    system("cls");
    if (userMark == 'X')
    {
        userMove();
        if (check() != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        comMove();
    }
    else
    {
        comMove();
        if (check() != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        userMove();
    }
}

//Telling whether the user won or lost after showing the grid
showGrid();
if(check() == 1)
{
    cout << "                                   You win!\n\n\n";
}
else if (check() == 2)
{
    cout << "                                  You lose!\n\n\n";
}



return 0;
}
```

Here are my functions:

```
    showExample()
{
    /*
    * Shows the numeric values for the places using cout
    */
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
    cout << "                                7  |  8  |  9   \n";
    cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
    cout << "                                4  |  5  |  6   \n";
    cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
    cout << "                                1  |  2  |  3   \n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
    cout << "\n";   
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************/

showGrid()
{
    /*
    * Shows the grid with all of the user's moves
    */
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n                              ";
    cout << "  " << grid[2][0] << "  |  " << grid[2][1] << "  |  " << grid[2][2] << endl;
    cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n                              ";
    cout << "  " << grid[1][0] << "  |  " << grid[1][1] << "  |  " << grid[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "                              _____|_____|_____ \n";
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n                              ";
    cout << "  " << grid[0][0] << "  |  " << grid[0][1] << "  |  " << grid[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "                                   |     |      \n";
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************/

userMove()
{
    /*
    * Asks for input from the user and puts that in grid if there is no something already there
    */
    int input = 0;
    while(input<1 || input>9 || grid[input/3][input%3-1] != ' ')
    {
        showExample();
        showGrid();
        cout << "                Please enter the place you would like to mark: ";
        cin >> input;
        system("cls");
    }

    grid[input/3][input%3-1] = userMark;
    cout << "grid: " << grid[3][3] << endl;

    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************/

comMove()
{
    /*
    * Making the computer's move based on the difficulty level 
    */
    int move = 0;
    if(difficulty == 1)
    {
        do
        {
            Sleep(700);
            srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
            move = rand() % 9 + 1;
        } while(grid[move/3][move%3-1] != ' ');
    }
    else if (difficulty == 2)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    grid[move/3][move%3-1] = comMark;

    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************/

reset()
{
    /*
    * Resets the grid to the correct places using a for loop nested in a another for loop
    */
    for(int place=0, row=0; row<3; row++)
    {
        for(int column=0; column<3; column++, place++)
        {
             grid[row][column] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************/

check()
{
    //Checking for 3 in a row
    for(int position=0; position<3; position++)
    {
        if(grid[position][0] + grid[position][1] + grid[position][2] == userMark*3 || grid[0][position] + grid[1][position] + grid[2][position] == userMark*3)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(grid[position][0] + grid[position][1] + grid[position][2] == comMark*3 || grid[0][position] + grid[1][position] + grid[2][position] == comMark*3)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    //Checking diagonals for 3 in a row
    if(grid[0][0] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][2] == userMark*3 || grid[0][2] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][0] == userMark*3)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(grid[0][0] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][2] == comMark*3 || grid[0][2] + grid[1][1] + grid[2][0] == comMark*3)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Traditional C-style arrays have no range check. They just calculate an offset based on your indexes, adds the offset to the start of the array and then writes to that address.

In your case [3][-1] will give an offset of 3*3 - 1 = 8

If you look at [2][2] it will give an offset of 2*3 + 2 = 8

Consequently when you (incorrectly) access [3][-1] it happens to be the same as [2][2] because you have a 3 by 3 array.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Just to be clear, the [] operator is not actually accessing the -1th position of the 3rd array, but accessing the 9 position by accessing grid[8] due to the addition?

Comment: Well, correct.... (but your terminologi is not fully correct as grid[8] is wrong). The 9'th position corresponds to [2][2] and so does [3][-1] in your case. You shall of course fix your code to `grid[(input-1)/3][(input-1)%3]` so that grid index ranges are `[0..2][0..2]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will go look and fix that if needed at school tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing out of range array is an `undefined behaviour`. Thus means you may not get an error. You may got weird results like random results. So, the solution that you should make sure that your code does not lead to out of range problem.

About the -1 issue, the operator [] on array is a kind of addition:

`a[b]` is equal to `*( (a) + (b) )`

So, `a[-1]` is equal to `*((a)+(-1))`. Then, you are trying to enter the previous memory block of the a pointer.